# How can I get access to `index.hbs` if I had `home.hbs` set up?

Tags: ghost-blog

`home.hbs` is now set up as the landing page for the whole site. And I would love to use `index.hbs` as the index page for blog(showing latest posts etc.)

Or is there a way to disable redirection from `/page/1` to `index` when `home` is set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a hack to ghost core](http://mordaszewski.com/ghost-add-home-page-hack/) to enable this.

However, if you just want to add a landing page to your blog. I recommend hosting Ghost in a subdirectory like `/blog` and create your landing page separately without using `home.hbs`. See more [here](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/6344).

Answer (score 0):

The `home.hbs` file is built to be for only the home landing page. `index.hbs` is for the home page (if `home.hbs` doesn't exist) and all the other pages for pagination. If you want the same layout for everything, just delete the `home.hbs` file and the site will instead use `index.hbs` for the home page and for any further paginated pages.

Answer (score -1):

I haven’t tried it yet, but have you already tried `http://YOUR-GHOST-URL/index/`?

Comment: It leads to a 404.